# In Lua, is there a function that given a function, it returns its name as a string?

Tags: lua

Sorry if this is too obvious, but I am a total newcomer to lua, and I can't find it in the reference.

Is there a NAME_OF_FUNCTION function in Lua, that given a function gives me its name so that I can index a table with it? Reason I want this is that I want to do something like this:

```
local M = {}

local function export(...)
   for x in ...
     M[NAME_OF_FUNCTION(x)] = x
   end
end

local function fun1(...)
...
end

local function fun2(...)
...
end

.
.
.

export(fun1, fun2, ...)

return M
```

Comment: I could just pass the string to export myself, but I thought i'd ask because i think it is more elegant passing the func itself. Although it is too dificult to have since the name as it is in the source lives only in the source.

Comment: I think you are mistaken in this point `the name as it is in the source lives only in the source`. That is true for most static and compiled languages, but the dynamic/scripting languages dispatch the functions by looking up their names, so they can have late binding (and allow to rebind functions to monkey patch code, etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stringify object name in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800648/stringify-object-name-in-lua)

Comment: Although I agree that the original question and intention may be duplicate, the answers of the two questions are fortunately not duplicate but instead seem to me complementary. I for once, found in both threads information in one, that wasnt in the other. I dont know if they can be merged in some way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There simply is no such function. I guess there is no such function, as functions are first class citizens. So a function is just a value like any other, referenced to by variable. Hence the `NAME_OF_FUNCTION` function wouldn't be very useful, as the same function can have many variable pointing to it, or none.

You could emulate one for global functions, or functions in a table by looping through the table (arbitrary or _G), checking if the value equals x. If so you have found the function name.

```
a=function() print"fun a" end
b=function() print"fun b" end
t={
   a=a,
   c=b
}
function NameOfFunctionIn(fun,t) --returns the name of a function pointed to by fun in table t
   for k,v in pairs(t) do
       if v==fun then return k end
   end
end
print(NameOfFunctionIn(a,t)) -- prints a, in t
print(NameOfFunctionIn(b,t)) -- prints c
print(NameOfFunctionIn(b,_G)) -- prints b, because b in the global table is b. Kind of a NOOP here really.
```

Another approach would be to wrap functions in a table, and have a metatable set up that calls the function, like this:

```
fun1={
    fun=function(self,...)
        print("Hello from "..self.name)
        print("Arguments received:")
        for k,v in pairs{...} do print(k,v) end
    end,
    name="fun1"
}
fun_mt={
    __call=function(t,...)
        t.fun(t,...)
    end,
    __tostring=function(t)
        return t.name
    end
}
setmetatable(fun1,fun_mt)
fun1('foo')
print(fun1) -- or print(tostring(fun1))
```

This will be a bit slower than using bare functions because of the metatable lookup. And it will not prevent anyone from changing the name of the function in the state, changing the name of the function in the table containing it, changing the function, etc etc, so it's not tamper proof. You could also strip the tables of just by indexing like `fun1.fun` which might be good if you export it as a module, but you loose the naming and other tricks you could put into the metatable.

Comment: True about function being a value, but that does not mean it cant be a compound value, having the code of the function and a name as metadata associated with it. I understand it is just the Lua way: every function defined is just a lambda stored in a table with the key that the function definition names: "The statement

     function f () body end
translates to

     f = function () body end" , as per the Lua reference

Comment: true, but that key does not have to be a string. The following is entirely correct in Lua: `t={[function() print'foo' end]=function()print'bar'end, {}=function()print'baz'end}` So here the keys are respectively functions and tables. That said, the table contains the functions, not the other way around. You can attach metadata to a function, but it will always be "external, as in the examples I gave. In Lua, a function isn't a compound value, it's just the function, as fits Lua's philosophy of handing the tools that allow building anything

Comment: true, and I have nothing more to add :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is possible, here's an implementation of the export() function:

```
function export(...)
        local env = getfenv(2);
        local funcs = {...};
        for i=1, select("#", ...) do
                local func = funcs[i];
                for local_index = 1, math.huge do
                        local local_name, local_value = debug.getlocal(2, local_index);
                        if not local_name then
                                break;
                        end
                        if local_value == func then
                                env[local_name] = local_value;
                                break;
                        end
                end
        end
        return env;
end
```

It uses the [debug API](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.html), would require some changes for Lua 5.2, and finally I don't necessarily endorse it as a good way to write modules, I'm just answering the question quite literally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/tostring

tostring( x ) should hopefully be what you are looking for

Comment: I was skeptical that this works, so I tried it, and it seems it doesn't: http://codepad.org/uaZ2zSXW

Comment: Oh, admittedly I was presuming a little.. :(

Comment: string.format also doesnt work. There doesnt seem to be any appropriate format option...

Comment: There's a similar SO thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800648/stringify-object-name-in-lua which suggests that there's no good solution to this..

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong (and I probably will, because I actually never programmed in Lua, just read a bunch of papers and articles), internally there is already a table with function names (like `locals` and `globals` in Python), so you should be able to perform a reverse-lookup to see what key matches a function reference.

Anyway, just speculating.

But the fact is that looking at your code, you already know the name of the functions, so you are free to construct the table. If you want to be less error prone, it would be easier to use the name of the function to get the function reference (with `eval` or something like that) than the other way around.

Comment: You are right. But after digging into it , the closest thing i could get to is the debug.getinfo function. But it does not return the name. Also the _G global table doesnt mention local functions. I am still searching for an introspection way to acquire the name from the object, or like you said, the other way around: the object from the name. But no luck so far.